# How to check min and max dates for all the tables in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

assuming I have a common date column name in all my tables called EDW_Beg_Date, and I need to check the min and max date for all the tables in the database at once. I am checking different stuffs which most of it I have researched and done but stock on the min and max date. Below is some sample of what I have done. I know i should use the sys.types, but what i don't know is how to make it show for each table. Let know what you think.

```
use EDW
go

--drop table #tempRowCount
create table #tempRowCount
(TableName varchar(255),
 TotalRowCount int,
 ActiveRowCount int)
 --EDW_Beg_Date datetime)

 --drop table #tempSQLQuery
 create table #tempSQLQuery
 (CommandId smallint Identity(1,1),
 SQLCommand varchar(2000))


 insert into #tempSQLQuery (SQLCommand)
select 'insert into #tempRowCount (TableName, TotalRowCount) select ''' + + e.name + '.' + s.name + ''' as TableName, count(*)  as TotalRowCount from ' + e.name + '.' + s.name  
from sys.tables s
inner join sys.schemas e
on s.schema_id = e.schema_id
where type = 'U' and e.name <> 'pdss' 


select * from #tempSQLQuery 

declare @CommandId smallint,
        @SQLStatement varchar(2000)

While exists (select * from #tempSQLQuery)
begin 
    select top 1 @CommandId = CommandId, @SQLStatement = SQLCommand from #tempSQLQuery order by CommandId

    execute (@SQLStatement)

    delete from #tempSQLQuery where CommandId = @CommandId
end


 **insert into #tempSQLQuery (SQLCommand)
 select 'update #tempRowCount set ActiveRowCount = R.ActiveRowCount
         from #tempRowCount A
        inner join (select ''' + + e.name + '.' + s.name + ''' as TableName, Count(*) as ActiveRowCount 
                    from ' + e.name + '.' + s.name + '
                    where EDW_Active_Ind = ''Y'' ) R

        on A.TableName = R.TableName'** 


 from sys.tables s 
 inner join sys.schemas e
 on s.schema_id = e.schema_id
 inner outer join sys.columns c
 on s.object_id = c.object_id
 where type = 'U' 
 and e.name <> 'dss' 
 and c.name LIKE '%EDW_Active_Ind%'




 While exists (select * from #tempSQLQuery)
begin 
    select top 1 @CommandId = CommandId, @SQLStatement = SQLCommand from #tempSQLQuery order by CommandId

    execute (@SQLStatement)

    delete from #tempSQLQuery where CommandId = @CommandId
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my thought, instead of creating a #temp table (with only one pound sign), create a ##temp table (stays available for as long as the session, instead of just the command).

Also, modify this:

```
 insert into #tempSQLQuery (SQLCommand)
select 'insert into #tempRowCount (TableName, TotalRowCount) select ''' + + e.name + '.' + s.name + ''' as TableName, count(*)  as TotalRowCount from ' + e.name + '.' + s.name  
from sys.tables s
inner join sys.schemas e
on s.schema_id = e.schema_id
where type = 'U' and e.name <> 'pdss'
```

So instead of inserting your "insert" statement, just do an actual "Exec('SQLStatementHere')".  It appears as though you added alot of unneccessary code/queries to accomplish your task.

Comment: @ ganders, Sure I will work on the performace issues once I get all I need for this code. Thanks for your contribution.